# Refactored fetch function for users doesn't load info to collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a function that if I use it on the ViewController returns to the collection view cell the required information and populates their cells.
When I tried to move all functions to a Service Page, refactoring, when I try to use it (the refactored function), the data is printed but not loaded to the collection view.

Please check my code what I am missing?

```
//Service class, where I wanna keep my firebase functions.
class Service {
static let shared = Service()
let hub = JGProgressHUD()

func retrieveUserDogs(uid: String, data: Array<Any>, collectionView: UICollectionView, view: UIView) {
    let uid = uid
    hub.show(in: view)
    let DB_BASE = Dogs_Ref.child(uid)
    var newValue = data
    DB_BASE.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let infoIndex = UserDogs()
            infoIndex.imageUrl = (dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as! String?)!
            infoIndex.userDogUid = (dictionary["dogUid"] as! String?)!
            newValue.append(infoIndex)
            if snapshot.value != nil {
                let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: infoIndex.imageUrl)!)
                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
                    (data, response, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    }
                }
                task.resume()
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2){
                    collectionView.reloadData()
                    self.hub.dismiss(animated: true)
                }
            } else {
                print("No Data")
            }
        }
        print(snapshot)

    }, withCancel: nil)
  }
}

  //cellforRowAt
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DogCell", for: indexPath) as! DogCell
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell.dogImageView.layer.opacity = 0.5

    let index = dogsArray[indexPath.row]
    print("The index value is: \(index)")
    print("The imageurl value is: \(index.imageUrl)")

    cell.dogImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: index.imageUrl )) { (image, err, type, Url) in
        print(index.imageUrl)

    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = dogsCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! DogCell
    let dogUID = cell.dogId
    print("The result is: \(dogUID)")
    cell.dogImageView.layer.opacity = 0.5
    cell.dogImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.dogImageView.clipsToBounds = true

}
```

Please note, If I remove the parameters, from the function and use it straight in the view controller everything will work - See the function below:

```
  func retrieveUserDogs() {
    hud.show(in: self.view, animated: true)
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let DB_BASE = Database.database().reference().child("Dogs").child(uid!)
    DB_BASE.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let infoIndex = UserDogs()
            infoIndex.imageUrl = (dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as! String?)!
            infoIndex.userDogUid = (dictionary["dogUid"] as! String?)!
            self.dogsArray.append(infoIndex)
            if snapshot.value != nil {
                let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: infoIndex.imageUrl)!)
                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
                    (data, response, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    }
                }
                task.resume()
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1){
                    self.dogsCollectionView.reloadData()
                    self.hud.dismiss(animated: true)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No Data")
                }
            }
            print(snapshot)

        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

Comment: where do you call retrieveUserDogs?

Comment: At the View Controller - I call it using: Service.shared.retrieveUserDogs(uid: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "", data: self.dogsArray, collectionView: dogsCollectionView, view: view).

Comment: The data from the fetch works, I do see the information I need at the console, but it's not loaded to the collection view cell. When I print the data there, I don't get anything.

Comment: What's the `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` for? It smells like the attempt to make an asynchronous task synchronous. Don't do that. And the returned `data` of the data task is not used at all.

Comment: I was using on the function before refactoring, in order to reload the collection view.

Comment: Any idea what could I do? In the end I am trying to create a function to retrieve all dogs in this list. I wanted to use a clean an easier way to call it

Comment: I added the function that If I use on the MainViewController it fetches and presents correctly the data at the collection view cell

Comment: where do you update array your collectionView based on? Check object in cellForRow after you call reloadData

Comment: I think you should reload collection after data received, don't use delay for it

Comment: Great, worked... Thanks!